# How much energy can an adapted Borg shield absorb?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, borg

We see in several episodes of several series that the Borg can adapt their shield frequencies and apparently become completely impervious to attack. However, I'm wondering if there is a limit to this that was ever explained in canon. I find it difficult to believe that the shields can really just shrug off any attack they've adapted to. Is there a limit to their ability to handle incoming energy?

Comment: 1.6T plot-o-watt-hours